# Select 1 random record per category using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a single large table conveniently called `mytable`, with three columns: `id`, `cat_group`, `cat_other`. I would like to select a random element from each `cat_group` using SQL. How can I do it?

**Example data**

```
| id | cat_group | cat_other |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | red       | fred      |
|  2 | blue      | sarah     |
|  3 | blue      | peter     |
|  4 | green     | spot      |
|  5 | red       | peter     |
```

**Acceptable result**

```
| cat_group | id | cat_other |
+-----------+----+-----------+
| red       |  5 | peter     |
| blue      |  2 | sarah     |
| green     |  4 | spot      |
```

**Also good**

```
| cat_group | id | cat_other |
+-----------+----+-----------+
| red       |  1 | fred      |
| blue      |  3 | peter     |
| green     |  4 | spot      |
```

I have seen some similar questions on SO, but I get lost in the implementation specifics. I'm using postgresql, but the answer should be able to be generalised across different databases.

Sqlfiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/b42c8/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way, using `row_number()`:

```
select cat_group, id, cat_other
from (select mytable.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cat_group order by random()) as seqnum
      from mytable
     ) as t
where seqnum = 1
```

The same idea works in other databases.  However, the random number function may differ.  For instance, in as SQL Server, `rand()` returns only one value per query -- as opposed to per row.  There you would use `newid()`.

Comment: The last line in the question: "I'm using postgresql, but the answer should be able to be generalised across different databases"

Comment: I have edited the answer to work with postgresql - please fix if not correct.